# How to send Ctrl+Alt+F1 (and other special keystrokes) to X window?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xorg

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F{1..12}</kbd>, it switches me to other virtual terminal.

Even `xte "keydown Control_L" "keydown Alt_L" "key F1" "keyup Alt_L" "keyup Control_L"` leads to switching to vt instead of sending that keys to focused window.

Use cases of this includes (but not limits to) sending special keystrokes to VNC or virtualization clients to be handled by clinet/guest system instead of the host one. Sometimes (like in VirtualBox) applications explicitly map some special alternative keystroke to that special ones (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in VirtualBox), but I want clean and universal solution.

Comment: The answer depends on which VNC client you're using; each has a different way of doing this. Which VNC client are you using?

Comment: I want universal solution for any X programs, not any VNC or virtual machine client -specific ones.

Comment: I think you just need to run `xte` on the remote machine, rather than the local machine.

Comment: It's not about local or remote things at all (this is just one use case). It is about delivering arbitrary key presses to X applications in general.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your question, then?

Comment: Done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's call <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> (where <kbd>Fx</kbd> is one of function buttons: <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>...) srvr keys.
There is a way to disable/enable srvr keys on the fly. By disabling I mean that X11 do not swallow them, but passes to window manager (kwin in kde).
For diabling srvr keys, you run `setxkbmap -option srvrkeys:none`
For enabling srvr keys, you run `setxkbmap -option`
To check if *srvr_ctrl(no_srvr_keys)* flag is enabled, run `setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols`

In kde there is possibility to perform window actions (for example, execute some command when window gets or looses focus). So you can automatically disable srvr keys when your special application window is focused, and automatically enable them back when it looses focus. It is universal solution. Useful for such applications as TeamViewer, VirtualBox, Chrome Remote Desktop, ipkvm viewer, krdc and so on.
If you interested, here is my script that I use for this thing: https://github.com/Ashark/aten-ip8000/blob/master/srvrkeys

Comment: Thanks, very useful for using Teamviewer at a console.

Answer (score 1):

For VirtualBox, try the key combination *REL* + F1. Here, *REL* is the key used to release the mouse grab in the VirtualBox window, usually right Ctrl or Alt key.

Comment: @diago better now?

Comment: The question is not about VirtualBox or VMWare (however the VMWare analogue of REL+F1 whould be interesting) or even about VNC clients, it's about "In general". /* trying to do it with `xte` */

Comment: in virtualbox it's called Host key

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send Ctrl+Alt+F[1..12] because the virtual terminals are seperate from the desktop that the VNC is connected to.

Comment: Unclear. I expect if the "Ctrl+Alt+Fx" event goes into a VNC client then the client will cause VNC server to issue "Ctrl+Alt+Fx". The problematic part that "Ctrl+Alt+Fx" does not reach the client, being interpreted by Xorg.