# How to prevent Ctrl+Alt+F1 switching off from X?

Tags: linux, keyboard, virtual-console

How to change this sequence to, for example "Ctrl+Fn+F1" or temporarily disable it?

@related: [How to send Ctrl+Alt+F1 (and other special keystrokes) to X window?](https://superuser.com/questions/231798/how-to-send-ctrlaltf1-to-window-to-switch-terminal-remotely-not-locally)

Answer (score 1):

```
Section "ServerFlags"
Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
EndSection
```

to xorg.conf

Ctrl+Alt+F1 however does not work into VMWare across VNC. May be this option just disables VT switching but still messes with Ctrl+Alt+Fx keys?