# Send special keys to virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I do most of my computer work in Ubuntu, when I need another OS I just use VirtualBox or VMWare Player. Sometimes when I'm in a Linux VM, I want to change to the console or use <kbd>SysRq</kbd> keys. I obviously can't just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> because that will switch to the console on my host OS

So my question is: Is there a way to send special key combinations to the guest OS only?

The answer at [How to send Ctrl+Alt+F1 (and other special keystrokes) to X window?](https://superuser.com/questions/231798/how-to-send-ctrlaltf1-and-other-special-keystrokes-to-x-window?rq=1) doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using virtualbox:

As stated [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html), if you want to do something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+(?), you just use the Host Key + your key, in your case, Host Key + F1

If you are using VMWare:

Follow [this](https://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-5/index.jsp#com.vmware.fusion.help.doc/GUID-995D006E-0CB3-404A-B680-983CD0A4DDAE.html)

Another option is to use the virtual keyboard on the guest OS, for example, in Windows, go to Start>All Programs>Accessories>Ease Of Access>On Screen Keyboard